# typeorm returns invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xc1

Tags: typescript, postgresql, utf-8, ascii, typeorm

I restored a postgres database with SQL_ASCII encoding. When trying to list some non-numeric data with some special character, the typeorm returns this error.

[image]

Comment: (1) Was the database "ASCII" before? (2) Why do you think it makes sense to use "SQL_ASCII" rather than utf8 encoding for utf8 data?

Comment: I received only the .backup and the instruction was to restore as SQL_ASCII and template0.

Comment: Restoring as template0 also sounds very odd. I suggest you go back to whoever sent you the backup and try to get an explanation.

Comment: Well, it's the way they work. They have an MVC system and want to make an API to be able to create an application for mobile devices.

Comment: Well, if they want to restore to `template0`, they don't know what they are talking about. They had better get a decent consultant.